# Facing issue in google people api format issue "googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: people version: v1"

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I tried to update the email address using people api (python). here is my code. please suggest me the correct format to update the email address to the existing contacts.

```
service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl='https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest:updateContact?updatePersonFields=emailAddresses')   
    service.people().updateContact(
        resourceName=profileCode,
        body={"resourceName": profileCode, "etag": accessToken},
        updatePersonFields='test@gmail.com',
    ).execute()
```

Here is my Code, can you please correct me.

```
FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='1*****.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    client_secret='Secret',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',
    user_agent='contact_cms/YOUR_APPLICATION_VERSION')


def get_credentials(FLOW):
    storage = Storage('info.dat')
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(FLOW, storage)
    return credentials

def get_http(credentials):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    return http

def update_a_google_contact(http):
    profileCode = 'people/c3022811234561887053'
    etag = '%EgU3AQI9abcdefMczZ1V0tVV1hubW89'

    service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl='https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
    service.people().updateContact(
        resourceName=profileCode,
        body={"resourceName": profileCode, "etag": etag, "updatePersonFields=emailAddresses": [{ "value": "test@gmail.com" }]}
    ).execute()

def main():
    creds=get_credentials(FLOW)
    http=get_http(creds)
    update_a_google_contact(http)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you using `http` and `discoveryServiceUrl` instead of `credentials`? You don't have a `credentials` file downloaded from your GCP project? Also, why specifying your `accessToken` in the `etag`? Also, please provide the code related to `http`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. please find the code. if it's wrong please help me to correct.

Comment: How did you come up with this code snippet? Why are you not using the regular flow, as shown in [the quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python#step_2_configure_the_sample)?

Comment: i'm new to this API. now i have changed the code to new one and found the solution. Many thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi! For documentation purposes, could you post an answer explaining what changes you did in order to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this to fix. instead of http.

```
service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
service.people().updateContact(
        resourceName='people/XXXXXX', 
        updatePersonFields="emailAddresses", 
        body={"etag": "XXXXXXX", "emailAddresses": [{"value": "XXXX@gmail.com"}]}).execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python)